# Does anyone know how to include the namespace prefix in your VSCode folder structure when running "sfdx force:source:retrieve"?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

When running "sfdx force:source:retrieve -x package_objects.xml" our folder structure does not include the prefix for our managed package.

For example we have a custom object "NewObject". The retrieve command creates a folder called :

force-app/main/default/objects/**NewObject**

instead of

force-app/main/default/objects/**namespace__NewObject**

Another issue that might be related is that our XML files for fields are also missing the namespace prefix :

```
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>customfield__c</fullName>
    ...
    <label>CustomField</label>
    ...
</CustomField>
```

instead of

```
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>namespace__customfield__c</fullName>
    ...
    <label>CustomField</label>
    ...
</CustomField>
```

Additional info :

This is for a 1GP package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Metadata API's design intent was to allow developers to work on separate branches of code in a Sandbox or Developer Edition org. As such, all metadata components are retrieved/pulled without reference to a namespace (or, `c` for components that always have a namespace), and the namespace is then patched in when you push/deploy. You will only receive the namespace for components that are *not* in your namespace, in order to migrate settings regarding installed packages in your org.